# how to get real image from ALAssetsLibrary

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I would like to get image from ALAssetsLibrary. I use the following code.But it doesn't work.My original image size is 2448 × 3264.But The result image from the following code is 640 X 852. I would like to have original image size 2448 X 3264. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary=[[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
                    [assetLibrary assetForURL:[[self.chosenImages objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset)
                     {
                         ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                         uint8_t *buffer = (uint8_t *)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*[rep size]);

                         NSUInteger buffered = (NSInteger )[rep getBytes:buffer fromOffset:0.0 length:[rep size] error:nil];
                         NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:buffered freeWhenDone:YES];//this is NSData may be what you want
                         UIImage *myImg =[UIImage imageWithData:data];
                          NSLog(@"myImg width and height %f and %f",myImg.size.width ,myImg.size.height);

                     }
                    failureBlock:^(NSError *err) {
                                     NSLog(@"Error: %@",[err localizedDescription]);
                    }];
```

Comment: Have you checked the image.scale property?

Comment: Finally I found that it is a bug of assets library. https://devforums.apple.com/message/1062519#1062519